# How to end the scroll action using appium driver in jav?

Tags: java, ios, scroll, appium

1. I am writing automation test case for iOS app using appium and java.
2. I need to do scroll action, I have tried with below code for scroll action.
3. I need to scroll till the particular web element and then i need to assert that particular element.
4. Below code scroll till the end of the page, after it reached to the end of the page, it tries to scroll down, so it throws error message.
5. I don't know how to end the scroll action, if particular web element is present means, I need to end the scroll action.

   ```
    while(AppiumHelper.isElementPresent(driver,By.name("Comment")) == false){
           System.out.println("1......");
              WebElement element = driver
                      .findElementByName("save_button");                       JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
              HashMap<String, String> scrollObjects = new HashMap<String, String>();
              scrollObjects.put("direction", "down");
              scrollObjects.put("element",
                      ((RemoteWebElement) element).getId());

              js.executeScript("mobile: scroll", scrollObjects);

            }
   ```

Comment: i am not sure who does it work in javascript but in java you can simply use scrollTo() method or TouchAction class.

Comment: @Gaurav, Ya I know about scrollTo() and scrollExact() methods, but it works only on the context of clicking particular text. I want to scroll down to particular web element.

Comment: Yes, you can use TouchAction class

Comment: @Gaurav, How can I use touch action if an particular element is not visible on that page view means.

Comment: @Gaurav, Ok thanks for your reply

Answer (score 0):

You can use Xpath for locating the last object on that page/hierarchy.
The xpath to last element can be generated like-

("Your_Object_Xpath")[1]/../*[last()]

Give this object's visibility as a break parameter for your scrolling loop.